# Bubble sorting algorithm while loop functionality

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, while-loop, bubble-sort

For the following sorting algorithm in Python, I am not understanding how the while loop functions. Immediately after the line "while sortingComplete is not True:" is the line sortingComplete = True. Doesn't the latter line not meet the condition of the while loop and therefore it should exit out of the while loop? Why does the code continue to execute even though sortingComplete was changed to True in the very next line?

```
def main():
    sort_list()

def sort_list():
    my_list = [3,4,5,6,4,3,2,5,6,7,8,6,4,3,5,4,4,5,6]
    print "my_list:       ", my_list
    sortingComplete = False
    while sortingComplete is not True:
        sortingComplete = True
        for number in range(len(my_list)-1):
            if my_list[number+1] < my_list[number]:
                sortingComplete = False
                my_list[number], my_list[number+1] = my_list[number+1], my_list[number]

print "Sorted my_list:", my_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The condition is checked only once per iteration, on the `while` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way loops work is once you enter a loop (that is once the **conditions** for the loop are satisfied) we perform all the instructions/statements in the loop before we again check if now the **conditions** are met to exit the loop.

In this case before we enter the `while` loop the **condition** `sortingComplete` is set to `False`. So even though the next line `sortingComplete = True` changes the value of `sortingComplete` variable we still have the rest of the statements to go before the we can check if **conditions** are met or not to exit the loop. Your `while` loop has another loop inside, the `for` loop.

The `for` loop goes through the array at each position number by number until the second last position. Each time checking ***if the current position number is larger in value to the next position number*** in the `my_list` array (I am assuming you understand the how bubble sort works so I am not going too much in detail). Until the sorting of the array is complete and perfect the `if` statement in the `for` loop will also be true and this `if` statement always changes the value of `sortingComplete` to `False`.

When we exit the `for` loop (when number = size of my_list array - 1) we reach the end of the `while` loop, where because of the `if` statement in the `for` loop the value of `sortingComplete` is now set to `False` so when it is time to check the `while` loop **condition** (`if sortingComplete not True`) the code repeats since `sortingComplete = False`.

The `while` loop ends when `my_list` array is sorted in an ascending order. That is the `if` statement **conditions** in the `for` are never met (never true), meaning the current position number value is always less or equal than the next position number value in the `my_list` array.

Hope this clears things up for you.